# Shell script in init.d not starting on boot

Tags: boot, bash, scripts, init.d

I have to create a devil that starts on boot. It is currently in /etc/init.d and I've created a symlink in /etc/rc5.d since my runlevel is 5, but the "start" case in the script wont start during boot. What am I doing wrong? Shall I try something different from init.d? Thanks in advance

```
#!/bin/bash
case "$1" in
    start)
        cato=$$
        if [ -e devil.pid ]
        then
            echo "Already running"
            sleep 3
        else
            sleep 1
            echo $$ > devil.pid
            echo "$datee Running service with PID: $cato" >> devil.log
            while true
            do
                datee=$(date +"[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S]")
                echo "$datee I'm alive" >> devil.log
                sleep 3
            done
        fi
        ;;
    stop)
        if [ -e devil.pid ]
        then
            cato=$( cat devil.pid )
            echo "$datee Stopping service with PID: $cato" >> devil.log
            sleep 1
            kill -9 $cato
            rm -rf devil.pid
        else
            echo "I'm dead"
            sleep 2
        fi
        ;; 
    restart)
        if [ -e devil.pid ]
        then
            cato=$( cat devil.pid )
            kill -9 $cato
            rm -rf devil.pid
            echo $$ > devil.pid
            while true
            do
                echo "Restarting with PID $cato" >> devil.log
                sleep 2
            done
        else
            echo "I'm dead"
            sleep 2
        fi
        ;;
esac
```

Comment: You're looking for/using `devil.pid` in the current directory. The "current directory" is different for `/etc/init.d` scripts, Use something like `/var/run/devil.pid`

Comment: Thx! This helped a lot